# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 on maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working on a java module using maven to build, all of my code builds successfully on `main/java`, but when I try to start creating the tests and I instantiate a class from the `test/java` folder the build fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I'm using intelliJ in a mac, and when I check my (only) java version installed I get this:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Same for javac.

I've tried the following:

- Invalidate Cache and restart IntelliJ
- Check the java compiler settings on IntelliJ (everything is set to 1.6)
- Delete the javax folder on my .m2 directory so maven downloads it again
- Double checked the versions on my pom

I can't build with java 7 because then it will break a huge deal of code because Im working on a module that will interact with a java 6 built project.

It makes no sense to me because this happens only when the code is in a jUnit test case, otherwise it works!

Your help is very appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate question... because none of the existing questions talks about the version of the TryCatchFinally version. Some people are just trying to earn badges or something...

Comment: Why do you think building with Java 7 means you can't work with Java 6 output?

Comment: Im afraid I will get the same error I'm getting with javax.servlet package here... it was built with java 7, and Im with java 6, and its driving me crazy...

Comment: Why would you get the same error? Your error is telling you that you're trying to run NEW code with an OLD version of Java. Running OLD code with a NEW version of Java is fine.

Comment: the thing is that this old code compiled with a new version will run in an old version, so at the long road it will be new code running in an old version of java...

Comment: If you search with `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally` in maven or via findjar.com, you'll find maven dependencies. Do not forget `<scope>provided</scope>`. Or look in your local .m2/repository for the used dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that the `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally` class that you have in dependencies has been compiled with Java 7 while you're only on 6.

I suspect the reason is that your servlet, JSP or taglib dependency is on a version built for Java 7 and you'd have to downgrade it.

What dependencies do you have in there?

**EDIT**: It looks like JSP 2.3 is part of Java EE 7: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history. I think you're out of luck here and the only options are using Java EE 6 (downgrading the JSP dependency to 2.1 or 2.2) or upgrading to Java 7.

Comment: how can I get a java 6 built version of the package with maven?

Comment: I have 2 dependencies: spring-webmcv 4.0.4.RELEASE, and javax.servlet.jsp-api 2.3.1, I can't change the javax version because its in a parent pom which is used by more packages (a lot more).

Comment: It looks like JSP 2.3 is only part of Java EE 7.

Comment: I downgraded my artifact to version 2.2.1-b03, and I finally got BUILD SUCCESS! thanks for the clues bro! your rock :)